# Azure Storage - File Share - Move 16m files in nested folders

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-file-copy

Posting here as server fault doesn't seem to have the detailed Azure knowledge.

I have a Azure storage account, a file share. This file share is connected to a Azure VM through mapped drive. A FTP server on the VM accepts a stream of files and stores them in the File Share directly.
There are no other connections. Only I have Azure admin access, limited support people have access to the VM.

Last week, for unknown reasons 16 million files, which are nested in many sub-folders (origin, date) moved instantly into a unrelated subfolder, 3 levels deep.

I'm baffled how this can happen. There is a clear instant cut off when files moved.

As a result, I'm seeing increased costs on LRS. I'm assuming because internally Azure storage is replicating the change at my expense.

I have attempted to copy the files back using a VM and AZCOPY. This process crashed midway through leaving me with a half a completed copy operation. This failed attempt took days, which makes me confident I wasn't the support guys dragging and moving a folder by accident.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to just instantly move so many files (how)
2. Is there a solid way I can move the files back, taking into account the half copied files - I mean an Azure backend operation way rather than writing an app / power shell / AZCOPY?
3. So there a cost efficient way of doing this (I'm on Transaction Optimised tier)
4. Do I have a case here to get Microsoft to do something, we didn't move them... I assume something internally messed up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A tool that supports server-side copy (like [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10)) can move the files quickly because only the metadata is updated.  If you wants to investigate the root cause, I recommend opening a [support case.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) (To sort this out – Your best bet is to connect with our Azure support team by filing a ticket, our support team on best effort basis can help you guide on this matter. )

Comment: I would, but I only have basic support on this subscription. Is there a way to raise a ticket for this without paying for the high support packages?